# N-queen examples - Discrete Mathematics, Kenneth Rosen (pg-33)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

> [image]

From the first paragraph and Q1 we see that the author chose i is a row and j column in p(i,j)
Then in Q2, we see that innermost loop is of k, which designates row of second coordinate in Q2.

The description specifies that Q2 asserts that there is at most one queen in each row, but innermost loop makes conjunction of the column values from j+1 to n . How does that make sense?
I have a sense that Q2 asserts for columns, not rows.

> [image]

It's the opposite, assertion works for rows, at most 1 queen in a row.

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, maybe write down what "loop" would create but not sure where to begin.

Thank you.

Edit:
[[Full example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrZMQ.png)] [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrZMQ.png)

Comment: Can you specify edition, section, etc.? My copy (7E) discusses the n-queens problem in Sec. 11.4 on spanning-tree backtracking applications, but the treatment there is very different.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Yes I should have included full example, I added 3rd image to the post with full example, it's 8th edition, section 1.3, example 10, page 33-34. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does appear to me like there's a typo in the second paragraph and the Q2 expression; it seems like it's accidentally flipping between $p(i, k)$ in some places and $p(k, j)$ in others. I'd replace the $p(k, j)$ expressions with $p(i, k)$.

Perhaps there was a copy-paste error from Q3 where $p(k, j)$ appears to be correctly used. Probably a good thing to send in an errata note to the publisher contact.

Comment: Note sent to Mcgraw Hill. I can't upvote as I have only 13 rep. I'm relieved it wasn't my failure and I noticed a mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @SandroJijavadze did they reply to your email? And did they confirm the error? Do you know where to find the up-to-date errata for 8th edition?

I also asked myself why my formular is p(i, k), but the author's is p(k, j).
The next sentence in the book confirms the mistake.

Comment: Beside the mistake, the book doesn't prove that Q = Q1 ∧ Q2 ∧ Q3 ∧ Q4 ∧ Q5 is satisfiable.

Is there a way to prove this just by using logical equivalences?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle
"Solutions exist for all natural numbers n with the exception of n = 2 and n = 3."